# Про использование build tags в golang

Tags: golang

Тут у меня возникает вопрос про использование `-tags` при `go build`. Я пытаюсь приспособить этот механизм для того что-бы задавать конфигурацию по-умолчанию. Например - есть файлы:

```
$GOROOT/src/sample/app/main.go
$GOROOT/src/sample/app/aflag.go
$GOROOT/src/sample/app/zflag.go
```

Содержимое файла **main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type appConfig struct {
    Debug bool
    Mode string
}

var config *appConfig

func init() {
    fmt.Println("main::init()");
    if config == nil {
        fmt.Println("main::set_config()");
        config = &appConfig{
            Debug: true,
            Mode: "Development",
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Current config is:", config)
}
```

Содержимое файла **afalg.go**

```
// +build aflag

package main

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("aflag::init()");
    if config == nil {
        fmt.Println("aflag::set_config()");
        config = &appConfig{
            Debug: false,
            Mode: "Production",
        }
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла **zfalg.go**

```
// +build zflag

package main

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("zflag::init()");
    if config == nil {
        fmt.Println("zflag::set_config()");
        config = &appConfig{
            Debug: false,
            Mode: "Testing",
        }
    }
}
```

Собираем три бинарника:

```
$ go build             -o bin/main   sample/app
$ go build -tags aflag -o bin/main-a sample/app
$ go build -tags zflag -o bin/main-z sample/app
```

Теперь запускаем и смотрим что получилось:

```
$ ./bin/main
main::init()
main::set_config()
Current config is: &{true Development}
```

Тут все хорошо, получилась версия для разработки. Так как ее проще всего запускать как `go run src/sample/app/main.go`

```
$ /bin/main-a
aflag::init()
aflag::set_config()
main::init()
Current config is: &{false Production}
```

Тоже все верно, получилась версия для production сервера

```
$ /bin/main-z
main::init()
main::set_config()
zflag::init()
Current config is: &{true Development}
```

Oops, что-то пошло нет так - получилась версия для разработчика, из-за того что сначала отработал `init()` из файла `main.go`, а затем `init()` из файла `zflag.go`

Собственно вопрос, как можно влиять на порядок выполнения функций `init()` из разных файлов?

Насколько я понимаю сейчас они выполняются в алфавитном порядке.

Comment: Попробуйте в aflag прописать `+build aflag,!zflag`, а в zflag - наоборот. Подозреваю, что у вас просто компилируются оба, так как один тэг другого не исключает.

Comment: Пробывал - не помогает. Смысл проблемы в том, что компилируется все правильно, но при запуске сначала запускается init() из main.go, а затем init() из zflag.go. А как указать порядок запуска - что-бы сначала запускалась функция из aflag.go/zflag.go а затем из main.go - непонятно

Comment: Ясно, тогда смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порядок вызова init-функций неопределён. Поэтому указывайте порядок явно, с помощью вызовов.

В main.go напишите

```
func init() {
    fmt.Println("main::init()");
    if config == nil {
        fmt.Println("main::set_config()");
        config = &appConfig{
            Debug: true,
            Mode: "Development",
        }
    }
    Init() // N.B.
}
```

А в aflag и zflag что-то типа

```
func Init() {
    config.Debug = false
    // ...
}
```

Comment: В этом случае получаем: src/sample/app/main.go:22: undefined: Init Если делаем build без flags, если его добавляем, то возникает ошибка: src/sample/app/main.go:12: Init redeclared in this block
 previous declaration at src/sample/app/aflag.go:7 при go build с -flags aflag или zflag. Тут у меня возникает странное подозрение что напрямую вызывать из main перекрывающиеся функции - не получается

Comment: @chernomyrdin Конечно, вам придётся ещё создать файл, который будет учитываться, когда ни один флаг не задан. И в нём, например, пустую функцию `Init`.

Comment: Идея правильная, но с делал чуть по-другому, оформлю как "Свой ответ на свой вопрос" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Итак у меня получилось следующее:

Файл **main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"

type appConfig struct {
    Debug bool
    Mode string
}

var config *appConfig

func main() {
    if config == nil {
        fmt.Println("main::set_config()");
        config = &appConfig{
            Debug: true,
            Mode: "Development",
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Current config is:", config)
}
```

Файл **aflag.go**

```
// +build aflag

package main

func init() {
    config = &appConfig{
        Debug: false,
        Mode: "Production",
    }
}
```

Файл **zflag.go**

```
// +build zflag

package main

func init() {
    config = &appConfig{
        Debug: true,
        Mode: "Testing",
    }
}
```

Таким образом инициализация конфига в `main.go` происходит после того как он возможно сконфигурирован в `aflag.go/init()` или `zflag.go/inint()`